# Evaluate $\int_{\pi f}^{3\pi f} dx \sqrt{\cos(x/f)}.$

Tags: integration, elliptic-functions

I am trying to do the following integral:

$$\int_{\pi f}^{3\pi f} dx \sqrt{\cos(x/f)}.$$

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(cos(x)%5C)%5E(1%2F2)+dx+from+x%3Dpi+to+3pi) gives me

$$\int_{\pi f}^{3\pi f} dx \sqrt{\cos(x/f)} = 4f E(2) = 2.39628f + 2.39628if,$$

where E is the elliptic function.

Mathematica also gives me the same answer. How can the integral of a *real* integrand with *real* limits be complex?

Comment: It isn't a real integrand!

Comment: The square root of a cosine function is not real?

Comment: That's right! What's $\sqrt{\cos\pi}$?

Comment: got it. you can put that as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the problem of the antiderivative $$I=\int \sqrt{\cos \left(\frac{x}{f}\right)}\,dx=f\int \sqrt{\cos \left(y\right)}\,dy=2 f \,E\left(\left.\frac{y}{2}\right|2\right)$$ The problem is that $E(z|2)$ has real values only $-\frac \pi 4 \leq z \leq \frac \pi 4$.